# Adding new portgroups to vmware virtual switches using pysphere

Tags: python, vmware

I'm trying to automate the addition of new portgroups to ESXi hosts using pysphere.  I'm using the following code fragment:

```
from pysphere import MORTypes
from pysphere import VIServer, VIProperty
from pysphere.resources import VimService_services as VI 

s = VIServer()
s.connect(vcenter, user, password)

host_system = s.get_hosts().keys()[17]
prop = VIProperty(s, host_system)
propname = prop.configManager._obj.get_element_networkSystem()
vswitch = prop.configManager.networkSystem.networkInfo.vswitch[0]
network_system = VIMor(propname, MORTypes.HostServiceSystem)

def add_port_group(name, vlan_id, vswitch, network_system):
    request = VI.AddPortGroupRequestMsg()
    _this = request.new__this(network_system)
    _this.set_attribute_type(network_system.get_attribute_type())
    request.set_element__this(_this)
    portgrp = request.new_portgrp()
    portgrp.set_element_name(name)
    portgrp.set_element_vlanId(vlan_id)
    portgrp.set_element_vswitchName(vswitch)
    portgrp.set_element_policy(portgrp.new_policy())
    request.set_element_portgrp(portgrp)
    s._proxy.AddPortGroup(request)
```

However, when I attempt to run it, I get the following error:

```
>>> add_port_group(name, vlan_id, vswitch, network_system)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 12, in add_port_group
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pysphere-0.1.8-    py2.6.egg/pysphere/resources/VimService_services.py", line 4344, in AddPortGroup
    response = self.binding.Receive(AddPortGroupResponseMsg.typecode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pysphere-0.1.8-    py2.6.egg/pysphere/ZSI/client.py", line 545, in Receive
    return _Binding.Receive(self, replytype, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pysphere-0.1.8-    py2.6.egg/pysphere/ZSI/client.py", line 464, in Receive
    raise FaultException(msg)
pysphere.ZSI.FaultException: The object has already been deleted or has not been completely created
```

I've attempted to swap in different values for "vswitch" and "network_system", but I haven't had any success.  Has anyone attempted to do something similar with pysphere successfully?

I can accomplish what I need through Powershell, which demonstrates that it isn't a vmware issue, but I don't want to use Powershell in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code on one of our vSpheres. 
It seems you are passing the object to set_element_vswitchName rather than the name. Maybe this will help:

```
vswitch = prop.configManager.networkSystem.networkInfo.vswitch[0].name
```